# How do i Convert an MP4 (H264,AAC) to WebM with zero quality loss using FFMPEG?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I have tried every flag suggested to convert an **MP4** video to **WebM** with **no quality loss** but nothing seems to work. output video quality is now where near the original.

```
ffmpeg -i lucy.mp4 -crf 20 lucy.webm  (method 1)

ffmpeg -i lucy.mp4 -crf 4 lucy.webm   (method 2)

ffmpeg -i lucy.mp4 -b:v 320k -q:v 0 output.webm (method 3)

ffmpeg -i lucy.mp4 -b:v 1M output.webm (method 4)
```

Im looking for a command to have a lossless conversion from mp4 to webm.

note : I  am not concerned about the output file size

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default encoder for WebM, libvpx, requires that if CRF mode is used, bitrate has to be set to 0. So,

```
ffmpeg -i lucy.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 4 -b:v 0 lucy.webm
```

Comment: thank you, it works. i've even tried **vp8, vorbis** codecs. I have noticed only one cpu is used by default during this conversion. ( so used **-threads**)

Comment: What are the other parameters?